# How to debug or break a hung thread in Visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

One of my threads got hung while running the application and I wanted to break into the thread and move ahead with the execution. My question may seem a little confusing but can someone please help me out on this ?

Comment: You need to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio : Debug : Attach to Process